# How to add a dynamic value for the component that has inline editing?

Tags: aem

How to add a dynamic value for the component that has inline editing? For ex: I want to add "Thanks for downloading software(need to populate the software name)"

Answer (score 0):

If its must to use inline editing,

1. One approach is to implement HTML parser, [sample here](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/html-parser-service.html) in conjugation with a logic pattern matching and replacement. Pass the a key=token in url and map it using i18n to get text to replace in token while parsing HTML

example URL -> /path/to/thankyou_page.html?softwareName=download-mysoftware

i18n key -> download-mysoftware and i18n translation as -> My Software

Your inline text could be - "Thanks for downloading software {softwareName}"

Your Regex could be - `"\\{(.*?)\\}"` i.e. anything in curly braces

If regex pattern matches while parsing html, identify the key in the pattern and check if it matches the key in url. In case it doesn't match do nothing render as is. But if it matches get the corresponding value from the request param. For that value use i18n library to get translation and substitute it.

2. Another perspective to look at your requirement is that inline editing is part of authoring however the messaging you need is more of a publish requirement. So what you could do is modify the above approach, instead of using HTML parsing, use a SlingModel to do the token replacement.